# Error 532 DB2 exception

Tags: sql, db2

When I tried to delete something in my DB2, this message appeared:

> -532   THE RELATIONSHIP constraint-name RESTRICTS THE DELETION OF ROW WITH RID X rid-number

What does this error mean and how can I resolve it?

What is the correct way to delete from my DB2? This is how I'm doing it now:

```
DELETE FROM LN_WIP WHERE NUM IN (500018605, 500018605, 500018605 ); –
```

Comment: This error looks like a DB2 error. Why did you tag it as `sql-server`?

Comment: sorry for add sql was my mistake

Answer (score 3):

Yep, you are most likely trying to delete a parent row, that has children rows. Please read [IBM Error Codes](http://www.sqlerror.de/db2_sql_error_-532_sqlstate_23504.html).

There is a **foreign key relationship** that is preventing the deletion of the parent row.

To find out which FK is preventing you from deleting the row, first you can list all the *exported* foreign keys in that table:

```
select
  substr(tabname,1,20) table_name,
  substr(constname,1,20) fk_name,
  substr(REFTABNAME,1,12) parent_table,
  substr(refkeyname,1,20) pk_orig_table,
  fk_colnames 
 from syscat.references where reftabname = 'LN_WIP';
```

Please post the result of this query. One of these is the culprit FK.

Comment: add the script in my post